# Autenticación con devise-token-auth y ng-token-auth no funcionan en el emulador de PhoneGap

Tags: angularjs, ruby, phonegap

He desarrollado una pequeña app con autenticación. En el back-end tengo ruby con la gema `devise-token-auth` y en el front-end AngularJS (Angular 1) con `onsen-ui` y el módulo `ng-token-auth`.

La app funciona perfectamente en el navegador, pero al probarla en el emulador de PhoneGap no funciona, no sucede nada cuando presiono los botones.

He seguido la documentación de cada sitio para crear mi app.

- https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth
- https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth

Modulo.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['onsen','ngResource','yaru22.angular-timeago','ngSanitize','ngSpecialOffer','ngStorage','ng-token-auth','ngRoute'])

        .config(function($authProvider) {
            $authProvider.configure({
                apiUrl: 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1',
                confirmationSuccessUrl: 'http://localhost:5000/confirmation-email'
            })
        })
```

Controlador de Login

```
 $scope.handleLoginBtnClick = function() {
    $auth.submitLogin($scope.loginForm)
        .then(function(resp) {

    })
        .catch(function(resp) {

    });
};


$scope.$on('auth:login-success', function(ev, user) {
    var options = {
        animation: 'slide', 
        onTransitionEnd: function() {}
    };
    myNavigator.resetToPage("main.html", options);
    console.log(user);
});

$scope.$on('auth:login-error', function(ev, reason) {        
    $scope.error = reason.errors[0];
    ons.notification.alert({
        message: ''+$scope.error+'',
        title: 'Error',
        buttonLabel: 'OK',
        animation: 'default', 
        callback: function() {
        }
    });
});
```

Formulario Login

```
<form ng-submit="submitLogin(loginForm)" role="form" ng-init="loginForm = {}">
    <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="loginForm.email" required="required" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Email" value="">

    <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="loginForm.password" required="required" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Password" value="">
      <br>
    <button type="submit" class="button login-button">Log in</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hola @Jefferson. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! ¿Podrías aclarar si se dispara algún error? ¿Cómo lo estás depurando? Además, sería bueno que incluyas el fragmento de código que realiza la autenticación

Comment: Hola @Mariano, aquí esta el modulo y el controlador que uso para la autenticacion. Lo hago tal y como esta en la documentación. Como mencione en el navegador si funciona, pero al probarlo en el emulador de Phonegap no.